# Segmentation fault with opencv function

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to detect a blob on a video feed with `cvBlob` lib. I think, I made a mistake with pointers, but I can't figure out where.
Moreover, do I have to free some of this variable?
The problem appears in row: `unsigned int result=cvb::cvLabel(src_g, labelImg, blobs);`

```
Mat& corridorProces(Mat& resultImg)
{   
    Mat srcMat=resultImg.clone();
    cvtColor( resultImg, resultImg, CV_RGB2GRAY );
    IplImage src= resultImg.clone();
    IplImage *src_g= new IplImage(src);
    IplImage *src_g_inv=new IplImage(src);
    cvThreshold(src_g, src_g_inv,35,255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    cvThreshold(src_g, src_g,40,255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);    
    IplImage *labelImg=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(src_g), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1);
    cvb::CvBlobs blobs;
    unsigned int result=cvb::cvLabel(src_g, labelImg, blobs);   
...
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57338/segmentation-fault-with-opencv-function/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-03-06**:
This question is not related to ROS. It's better suited in cvBlob project mailing list or similar, not here.

**Comment by [phbou72](https://answers.ros.org/users/4334/phbou72/) on 2013-03-06**:
Simply comment out all the code inside the function, and uncomment line by line until you find the one that give you a segmentation fault. It's not something related to ROS. It's a programming issue.

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2013-03-06**:
The weird thing is that the algorithm implenented in Opencv works for 1 image, but when I try it in ROS, where the cv_brigde returns a cv::MAT() and I convert into Iplimage, I receive segmentation fault error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I changed to: `IplImage *src_g=cvCloneImage(&src);` and now its working.
I dont understand why I got some times empty packages but now there is no more segmentation fault.

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0